# Are browsers still vulnerable to IDN homograph attacks?

Tags: web-browser, appsec, dns, chrome, firefox

Is it not possible for Chrome and Firefox to protect against this > [https://www.аррӏе.com/](https://www.%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D3%8F%D0%B5.com/)

Navigating to that above (fake) apple website using Firefox 59.0.2 doesn't actually take me to the apple website, but it still says apple[dot]com in my web browser...

References:

> https://www.xudongz.com/blog/2017/idn-phishing/
>
> https://thehackernews.com/2017/04/unicode-Punycode-phishing-attack.html
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack

Comment: It's simply a trade-off between security and usability. We have already discussed how browsers try to prevent these attacks and possible defense measures here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182680/how-to-defend-against-homograph-attacks/

Comment: If I recall, Chrome/Chromium has some resistance, and Firefox is still vulnerable.

Comment: In Chrome, that URL appears as `https://www.xn--80ak6aa92e.com/` both when I mouse over it and in the URL bar when I go to it.

Comment: In Firefox, it only does that if you set `network.IDN_show_punycode` to `true`.

Comment: Firefox shows punycode in the bottom left on mouseover, but shows utf8 in the url bar. The "l" is clearly not an l due to the font Firefox is using though.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald If I recall, a web page can spoof the bottom left mouseover bar, as Google for example does. It cannot be relied upon. See for example [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/152896/165253).

Comment: @forest I'd forgotten about that, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

No, Humans are vulnerable to the homograph attack, browsers are unaffected.

Chrome has a partial work-around that offers a false sense of security to those who buy the hype.

In the general case of the attack both domain names are IDN and the user can't be expected to differentiate between two different random-looking strings of ASCII characters.